# Monitoring stream sockets Java

Tags: java, sockets

Is there any way to monitor the stream data from any existing socket?

I mean, I want to create a socket that will catch all the stream from another socket and redirect it to my server. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this rather than using an existing tool designed for the job; e.g. stunnel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can implement your server that opens ServerSocket, reads from input stream and writes to output stream of other socket. Take a look on PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream. These classes may help you to implement your task.

But if you *just* want to see what is passed via network, why not to use WireShark?

Comment: In face, I don't know if I am going through the right way. I want to create a virtual network to play games, like Garena, Hamachi or RGC. So I wondered that I would need to catch warcraft traffic and redirect it to my server. Do you know if it is correct?